How do I config an OAuth processor/controller service to authenticate to a secure REST API via client credentials get an Access Token from Apache Nifi
How do I configure an OAuth 2.0 processor/controller service in Apache Nifi to authenticate to a secure REST API using StandardOauth2AccessTokenProvider and client credentials
Tried everything I could with configuring StandardOauth2AccessTokenProviderbut nothing worked.
I could configure a processor using HandleHttpRequest and connect to a non-authenticated REST API and get a response no problem.
I could also connect to the OAuth authenticated REST API using client credentials and get an Access Token using Python, do GET AND POST and get JSON responses no problem.
The REST API I am trying to use from Nifi is at https://support.haloservicedesk.com/auth/token

Can you share any more details? Specifically, any error messages you could share?
